# How to keep the value of selected item of a drop down after form submission in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am just building a simple search page in PHP. I need to know how can i keep the selecte value of the drop down list upon form submission. Currently, the value resets to the first index.

Can I do this via PHP without using client-side script?

Here is the code:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

mysql_select_db('hotel');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>


<form method="get">

<select name="field" id="field">

<?php

 /*if($field == 'Active')
 'selected="selected"';
 */

 while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo '<option>'.$rows['customer_id'].'</option><br>';
?>


</select>


<?php



if (isset($_GET['Search']) && $_GET['action']=='search')
{




  $sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customer_id=".$_GET['field'];

   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   echo '<br>Customer Name: '.$row['customer_name'].'<br>';
   echo 'Email Address: '.$row['Email_Addr'].'<br>';
   echo 'Contact No: '.$row['Contact_No'].'<br>';   

}


?>


<input type="hidden" name="action" value="search" />
<br><input type="submit" value="search" name="Search" onclick="" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

usually like this.

```
echo '<option';
if ($_GET['field'] == $rows['customer_id']) echo " selected";
echo '>'.$rows['customer_id'].'</option>';
```

And please don't use the `mysql_*` functions to write new code, especially when you are learning. The `mysql_*` functions are in the process of becoming deprecated, they will be removed in future versions of PHP. Use `mysqli_*` or PDO objects instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the get value is the same than the select value :

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo '<option value="'.$rows['customer_id'].'" '.($rows['customer_id'] == $_GET['field']?'selected="selected"':'').'>'.$rows['customer_id'].'</option><br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

When printing the select options, you can check for the value and set any mathing option to selected, maybe like this:

```
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if(!empty($_GET['field']) && $_GET['field'] == $rows['customer_id']){
        echo '<option selected="selected">'.$rows['customer_id'].'</option><br>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<option>'.$rows['customer_id'].'</option><br>';
    }
}
```